# NoClassDefFoundError at Runtime on class inside external .AAR library

Tags: java

So I run into this problem today. I got an exception saying

```
"NoClassDefFoundException" class com.example.app.MainClass$3
```

I know what this exception means so first I looked inside classes.jar file located in `/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/$packageName%/%versionName%/jars.`

There I found the "missing" class with exactly the same signature: `MainClass$3`. So it WAS generated. Then on my smartphone I went to `/data/app/%packageName%/` and looked inside `base.apk` file. Inside it I found a file named `classes.dex`. I opened it with Notepad++ and I found mentioning of my `MainClass$3` there as well! Why this class could not be found? What else should I check? I cannot post original exception messages nor files cause it's commercial, but I'll try to clarify things as much as I can if needed.

**UPDATE #1**: There is something I think I need to add. The odd thing about all of this is that this class is the only one that cannot be found from the whole library. It's not new, I added it long time ago, so I just thought, maybe some exception that occurred while running some code from that class causing this error?

**UPDATE #2:** I debugged my app and saw the strangest thing ever: I was able to call constructor of the problematic class with arguments and the object was SUCCESSFULLY CREATED. Then I called a method of the class and got this exception. Here is the method I call

```
public Observable<String> getSnapshotTaker() {
        int a = 1;
        Observable<String> snapshotTaker = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                queueSnapshot(true, 0, subscriber);
            }
        });
        return snapshotTaker;
    }
```

I inserted

```
int a = 1;
```

for debugging purpose. App crashes with the exception on the second line of the method, where I'm trying to create an Observable. So, it looks like it's not the class `SnapshotManager` which is causing the crash but rather this `Observable`. But why the exception message looks like this then?

**UPDATE #3:** Here is the stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.pack.SnapshotManager$3
    at com.test.pack.SnapshotManager.getSnapshotTaker(SnapshotManager.java:370)
    at com.test.pack.CameraPresenter.takePhoto(CameraPresenter.java:31)
    at com.test.pack.MainActivity$MainShutterClickListener.onClick(MainActivity.java:1100)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Can you post the actual stack trace?

Comment: I can, but only on Sunday :(

Comment: why not ask your question on sunday?

Comment: updated with much interesting information

Comment: Here is a similar question and answer. Please check it. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392296/class-not-found-in-aar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the source of the problem. First of all I noticed that NoClassDefFound exception was pointing at a wrong class. I mean it was not SnapshotManager who's "def" was not found but the Observable class from RxJava library. This is what was causing the exception:

- Main project which depends on a library I made.
- The library which depends on rxjava
- Main project calls some code from the library that uses rxjava classes
  and, as far as the main project has no rxjava dependencie, it crashes.

Solution is simple: if you have a library project with some external dependencies you should mention those dependencies in your main project as well. I know that it's not the best solution and that there might be a way not to do this, but this is what I came up with.

Comment: Is there any alternate solution