# Activity Class cannot be found in AAR file java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, android-activity, aar

I have created an android library, it contains an Activity Class that uses to open camera intent, the library works perfect excepts for the part that invokes the Activity to appear over the screen and the app crashes throwing following errors

```
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.me.scanner.ScannerViewActivity
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                    ... 14 more
         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Following is my `build.gradle` file of other project that will use this library

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.me.app:gpio_lib@aar'
    compile ('com.me.app:scanner@aar'){ transitive = true; }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Please Note:**

- This library works perfectly as module project,

  ```
  compile project(':scannercontrol')
  ```

  but not when using it as `aar` in the project
- I have tried with and without `{ transitive = true; }`, no change
- I have rename my aar file to `scanner.aar`
- I have taken the aar file form `/[library-project]/build/outputs/aar/scanner-release.aar`

**Update1 - 2017-09-14**

The activity `ScannerViewActivity` is part of my library, this is how it is been called from one of the library class

```
Intent scannerView = new Intent();
scannerView.putExtra(MESSAGE_RECEIVER, new MessageReceiver());
scannerView.setClass(context, ScannerViewActivity.class);
scannerView.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(scannerView);
```

this `context` is the instance of `android.app.Application` and not of any `Activity`

**Update2 - 2017-09-14**

Fortunately after roaming 2 days all over google I come across the answer of question [Class not found in aar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37393603/2552551). I have added the dependencies of the library to the project and able to run it with `aar` but this is not the solution of my issue,

**Following is the flow and issue I'm currently facing**

- I'm developing a sandbox version of a library that communicates with a specific barcode scanner hardware, since the developer doesn't necessarily have the hardware they will use the sandbox version of the library that will allow developer to use their device camera as a barcode scanner,
- We want the developer to extract the `AAR` files `scanner.aar` and `scanner-sandbox.aar` from provided `SDK` and use either of them
- We don't want the developer to add extra dependency to their `.gradle` file if they want to run the sandbox version of the library,
- Following is the dependency that is being used to simulate device camera as a barcode scanner

  ```
  compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
  ```

## The updated question is

What is the possible way to distribute an aar file without publishing them to any repository like **maven repository** and all dependencies of the library installed when developer syncs the `.gradle` file

Comment: check your dependencies in project module setting. you need to re-attach the dependency.

Comment: Right Click to your project > Open Module Setting. And you can see dependencies Tab. attach your file/library there.

Comment: can you find com.me.app:scanner folder in ~\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1

Comment: You missed the most important things for crashes: device model and Android version.

Comment: @lulian android version and device model are irrelevant to this issue

Comment: Have you tried to add this activity Explicitly in your manifest file?

Answer (score 5):

zeeshan

I have faced same issue i did lot of research & i fixed hopefully it helps you

> Creating .aar file for a project:
>
> 1. For a library module, .aar file is automatically created by Android Studio. For a project with the any resource file or with the
>      libraries, .aar file can be generated as mentioned in next steps.
> 2. Check the plugin. It should be in as follows, change to library if it is in application, apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
> 3. Open the open right border gradle bar and go to “your project”->Tasks->build and then double click on the assembleRelease.
>      On Building the project, You will find the two .aar
>      files(app-debug.aar and app-release.aar) inside app/build/outputs/aar/
>      directory. Using .aar file in your project:
> 4. Get the “app-release.aar” file and paste it in the libs folder of your project. If libs folder is not present, create a directory named
>      “libs” inside app directory.
> 5. Add the following to the app gradle file, repositories {
>      flatDir {
>          dirs 'libs'
>      } } dependencies {
>      compile(name:'app-release', ext:'aar') }
> 6. On sync, your project is ready to use the library files. Note : .aar gradle dependencies has to be added manually in your project app
>      gradle
>      Example:below

**Assumption of errors:  System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:**

***Solution:***

> .aar gradle dependencies has to be added manually in your project app
>   gradle

Answer (score 5):

The answer for your "Update2 - 2017-09-14" - can simply build a fat aar file. which will contain all the dependencies, one thing which you may have to handle is conflict in dependencies sometime may create a issue. also the size of the fat aar may be huge. so give try.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 ways to distribute your library:

1. Creating a local maven library then distribute the generated aar.
   You can create a local aar by using [Gradle Android Maven plugin](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin). How to make it:

   a. Add the plugin classpath to **root** `build.gradle`:

   ```
   buildscript {
     repositories {
       jcenter()
       mavenCentral()
     }
     dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
       classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'

     }
   }

   allprojects {
     repositories {
       jcenter()
     }
   }
   ```

   b. Set the maven plugin, and add group and version name to library build.gradle:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
   apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

   group = 'com.your.packagename'
   version = '1.0.0'
   ext.versionCode = 1000

   android {
     compileSdkVersion 25
     buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

     defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 9
       targetSdkVersion 25
       versionCode versionCode
       versionName version
     }
     buildTypes {
       ...
     }

   }

   dependencies {
     ...
   }
   ```

   c. Set the artifactId is set in settings.gradle:

   ```
   rootProject.name = 'yourlibraryname'
   ```

   d. Build and install the library to your local maven.
        You can run `./gradlew` install on project folder or use

   Gradle -> YourLibrary -> Other -> Install from Android Studio (on the right side of Android Studio)

   e. Use the installed library directly to your project.
      You can use the library by adding `mavenLocal()` to your **root** build.gradle

   ```
   allprojects {
     repositories {
       jcenter()
       mavenLocal() // for local maven.
     }
   }
   ```

   Then add the dependency to the project:

   ```
   compile 'com.your.packagename:modulename:1.0.0'
   ```

   Or you can copy the generated .aar from local maven path. In Linux, you can get it from `/your/userpath/.m2/repository/` or `~/.m2/repository/`
2. Use the same technique in number 1, but make the local maven path for each developer computer pointing to the `~/.m2/repository/` central.
3. Use a private maven repository.
   You can use [JFrog Artifactory oss](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) or [Nexus Repository OSS](https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype)

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the problem is that the class `ScannerViewActivity` is called inside one of your AAR as a dependency like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android{...}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.me.scanner:otherscanner@aar' //library which contains ScannerViewActivity
}
```

but when you use a aar (transitive won't add this aar dependencies !), you have to add the other dependency such as:

```
dependencies {
...
compile ('com.me.app:scanner@aar')// remove{ transitive = true; }
compile ('com.me.scanner:otherscanner@aar')
...
}
```

Comment: the activity is not part of any other library, it belongs to same library

Comment: @riksof-zeeshan Can you unzip the aar file, then inside unzip the `classes.jar` and check that `ScannerViewActivity.class` is there ?

Comment: this is the aar file created by myself, I have developed this module that works perfectly as project module in dependencies, but not as compiled aar

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know the root cause, you can try this solution: in your app project, define an activity extends from ScannerViewActivity, and declare it in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
class MyScannerViewActivity extends ScannerViewActivity {
    // do nothing or something you want
}
```

Then you should start MyScannerViewActivity instead of ScannerViewActivity by intent.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as below?

1. Disable Instant Run and clean build your AAR.
2. Deploy it again, where ever you are hosting your AAR.
3. Test the app again with AAR as the dependency.

Instant runs sometimes cause an issue due to caching.

Edit:
For adding local AAR. You can follow the answer as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506648/adding-local-aar-files-to-gradle-build-using-flatdirs-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. You can try using `fat-aar`, which can merge the library code into the aar, to solve this. https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android