# Gradle cant find plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to import an external library into my application, the library is FFmpeg. Here is a link to the [module](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java).

I add the library to my libs folder (after downloading it), then from File > New > Import module > select FFmpeg. Now within my apps build gradle I add the line

`compile project(':FFmpeg')`

Now when I try and sync the project I get this error:

> Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.

When I open the file, this is the affected line

> apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

Basically my end goal is to get the above lib into my project as an external library so I can modify the source code to fix some bugs within the library.

Any help is much appreciated, I have been trying to fix this problem for a really long time but I am not too good with Gradle besides just using dependencies.

**Update 1**

Apply problems are now fixed however it cant find variables like version name and rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion as Integer

> Error:(6, 0) Could not get unknown property 'VERSION_NAME' for project ':FFmpegAndroid' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the plugin to your classpath root build.gradle. You can found it in the [Gradle Android Maven plugin](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin). Something like this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    // This is the classpath for the plugin
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

You should look at the ffmpeg android [gradle.properties](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/blob/master/gradle.properties) and add it to your root project, here it is:

```
VERSION_NAME=0.3.2
VERSION_CODE=28
GROUP=com.writingminds

POM_DESCRIPTION=Java implementation of ffmpeg for Android
POM_URL=https://github.com/writingminds/ffmpeg-android-java
POM_SCM_URL=https://github.com/writingminds/ffmpeg-android-java.git
POM_SCM_CONNECTION=scm:https://github.com/writingminds/ffmpeg-android-java.git
POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION=scm:https://github.com/writingminds/ffmpeg-android-java.git
POM_LICENCE_NAME=GNU GPLv3
POM_LICENCE_URL=https://github.com/writingminds/ffmpeg-android-java/blob/master/LICENSE.GPLv3
POM_LICENCE_DIST=repo
POM_DEVELOPER_ID=hiteshsondhi88
POM_DEVELOPER_NAME=Hitesh Sondhi
```

The VERSION_NAME is needed in the Ffmpeg Android [build.gradle](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/blob/master/FFmpegAndroid/build.gradle):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.bintray"

// This is the library version used when deploying the artifact
version = VERSION_NAME

...
```

**ADVICE:**

It's better if you run the ffmpeg-android-java as independent project and then configure it so it can be installed to local maven. Read the details at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46330142/4758255

Comment: Hi this worked to solve the apply problems but now it cant find the version name or any of the other properties please look at updated question

Comment: Why would it be better to run as Maven? Thanks

Comment: Because you'll isolate the problem of the ffmpeg library to your code. Imagine if the library is updated because of a bug or improvement. How do you reflect the update to your code? If you directly include the library as your module, you'll need to reintegrate the library again which is tedious and error prone.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the **plugin** in your `buildscript` block. You can add in the top-level `build.gradle` file or in your `module/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        //..current plugins
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    }
}
```

About the variables not found you have to check the `build.gradle` in the library on [github](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/blob/master/build.gradle)

You have to define in your project these variables. Of course use your values.

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = '22.0.1'
    targetSdkVersion = 22
    minSdkVersion = 16
    versionCode = 28
    versionName = "0.3.2"
}
```

Comment: @RedGooseMental Check the answer